# Проблема с перезапуском программы/драйвера

Tags: c#, .net

Несколько раз на дню отлетает графический драйвер, и я бы хотел сделать цикличный перезапуск драйвера при помощи таймера.

Собственно, сам вопрос: как можно обратиться к процессу/службе и заставить его отключится, а потом повторно запустить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне можно это реализовать? Заранее спасибо!)

Я попробовал сделать у себя с помощью .net, но ничего не робит:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
            private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\Display.NvContainer\\NVDisplay.Container.exe");
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                Application.Exit();
            }
```

Comment: я конечно понимаю, что нет преград для программиста, когда он хочет писать код, но не проще ли выяснить и устранить причину вылетов драйвера? Это не нормальное поведение и может закончится весьма печально, если продолжать игнорировать или просто делать перезапуск драйвера, которому вообще-то нужны минимум административные права на запуск, а в общем случае нужны системные права.

Comment: @rdorn, я поинтересовался у гугла и узнал видеодрайвер отваливается по причине разгона видеокарты. Разгон я делал при помощи MSI Afterburner, разгон у меня в пределах разумного, ядро я не трогал, только разгон памяти (карточка MSI GTX 1050 Ti), добавил 1.5к МГц сверху (на сайте производителя указано как допустимый разгон). Драйвера стоят самые последние, поэтому даже не знаю что это может быть еще, мб есть еще варианты что можно сделать с драйверами? )

Comment: эту информацию лучше добавить в вопрос. Код ниже рабочий, но  случае драйвера он требует административных прав для своей работы. Без этого не получится остановить выполнение процесса, запущенного системой. Самый простой вариант - "запуск от имени администратора", чуть сложнее - оставить в коде из ответа только остановку и запуск процесса и во встроенном планировщике задать периодический запуск с учетной записью администратора. Можно еще пошаманить с манифестом, но это не сильно лучше ручного запуска (на пару кликов меньше) а по смыслу - то же самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде основная проблема в том, что вы не **перезапускаете** процесс, а просто запускаете новый экземпляр и тут же выходите (`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`) из собственной программы.

При этом вновь запущенный вами экземпляр, если в нем реализована логика единственного экземпляра (что весьма вероятно в данном случае), сразу же сам себя и закрывает.

```
private bool processing;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Не допускаем множественные вхождения в тело процедуры
    if (processing)
        return;  

    processing = true;
    try
    {  
    // Убиваем все процессы с заданным условием 
       System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
                                     .Where(x => x.ProcessName
                                                  .Equals("nvdisplay.container.exe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                     .ToList()
                                     .ForEach(x => x.Kill());
     // Запускаем новый экземпляр            
     Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Display.NvContainer\NVDisplay.Container.exe");
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         // Обработка ошибок
    }
    finally
    {
       processing = false;
    };
}

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       Application.Exit();
     }
```

Comment: при добавлении вашего кода в место моего у меня не получается перезапустить драйвера, я также пробовал указать другое приложение и проверить работу с ним, но все также(( кодить я начал не давно и хотелось бы разобраться, по поводу вот этой строки 'System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where(x =>x.ProcessName.Equals("nvdisplay.container.exe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Kill());' как здесь используется условие .ToList().ForEach(x => x.Kill()), можно ли без условия записать.ToList().ForEach.Kill()

Comment: @AlexandrZemlyak это linq, данная строчка означает закрыть все процессы соответствующие условию (nvdisplay.container.exe) не обращая внимания на регистр при сравнении имен процессов

Comment: @AlexandrZemlyak _можно ли без условия записать.ToList().ForEach.Kill()_: 

нет, синтаксис [лямбда-выражений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) именно такой: 
`x` — входной параметр для анонимной функции, 
`x.Kill()` — блок операторов над параметров.